# LLMNR on Windows vs. Zeroconf vs. Bonjour

Tags: windows, bonjour, zeroconf, mdns, windows-networking

[Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb878128) is a Microsoft tech for service discovery based on multicast DNS. Is it compatible with Bonjour/Zeroconf? If so, where's the API? The service discovery, I take it, is somehow rolled into vanilla DNS resolution (`gethostbyname()`?), but what about service advertisement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LLMNR solves a small subset of the problems that mDNS tackles, as set out in [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602230543/http://lists.apple.com/archives/rendezvous-dev/2004/Apr/msg00031.html). In short, it's not compatible with Bonjour.

Here is the content of that post, in case archive.org decides to drop the page:

> From: Marc Krochmal  Date: Fri, 16 Apr 2004 08:54:54
>   -0700
>   Hi Tom,
>
> > I was reading the August 2003 article in Linux Magazine
> >     (http://www.linux-mag.com/2003-08/zeroconf_01.html) on Zeroconf
> >     environments. Within the article they mention that Link Local
> >     Multicast Name Resolution was adopted by the IETF and that more or
> >     less mDNS was thrown out on its ear, even though it uses existing
> >     standards instead of creating an all new protocol. One of the reasons
> >     they mentioned or implied was that LLMNR was more advanced than mDNS
> >     was 'includes provisions to keep link-local addresses from
> >     accidentally being propagated into the greater DNS space' Based on
> >     research I have been doing into Rendezvous environments this is
> >     incorrect (is it not??) since mDNS is aware that domains ending with
> >     '.local' are available only on the local link and that a host will
> >     only ever try and resolve a domain name ending with '.local' on the
> >     local link. So have i misread this article or the mDNS white-paper or
> >     is there some truth in this??
>
> LLMNR is much less advanced than mDNS. LLMNR solves a very small
>   problem. It provides very basic name resolution when the name server
>   is misconfigured or when it returns an error.
>
> mDNS provides a distributed notification and cache coherency protocol
>   that facilities ad-hoc DNS-Based Service Discovery. mDNS also provides
>   reliable local name resolution when a hostname ends with ".local",
>   regardless of the state of the DNS server. LLMNR is not a service
>   discovery protocol. You could say that mDNS is a superset of LLMNR.
>
> After a year and a half of operational experience with mDNS, we have
>   never seen accidental leakage of link-local addresses outside the
>   local-link.
>
> There are many people in the IETF DNSEXT working group that would like
>   to see LLMNR interoperate with mDNS. In fact, some people including
>   Paul Vixie are saying that LLMNR should be thrown out and replaced
>   with mDNS. You can read this for yourself in the namedroppers
>   archives.
>
> http://ops.ietf.org/lists/namedroppers/namedroppers.2004/
>
> > Another thing alluded to by this article was that Microsoft is pushing
> >     for LLMNR and as far as I recall this is something provided by Service
> >     Pack 2 in Win XP.
>
> I am not aware of LLMNR being included in Service Pack 2.
>
> > Is this not going to take us back to a NetBIOS v AppleTalk days where
> >     instead of working towards a singular standard we now have two for
> >     name resolution in Zeroconf environments???
>
> This is difficult to predict. If Rendezvous continues to gain
>   momentum, it could easily become the standard in Zeroconf
>   environments. Pretty much every network enabled printer today ships
>   with Rendezvous. Rendezvous also enables iTunes Music Sharing on Mac
>   and Windows which could allow you to potentially share music with many
>   other devices in the home with zero configuration.
>
> > Finally on a different track, the mDNS responder provided by Apple for
> >     OS X handles traditional DNS responses as well as well as link local
> >     mDNS. Is the mDNS responder for Windows and Linux boxes intended to
> >     replace the respective traditional DNS handlers provided by the
> >     Windows OS and Linux OS or does mDNS work in conjunction with their
> >     existing DNS handling (i.e. On a windows box with an mDNS Responder
> >     installed, if a DNS Query (for a global domain) needs to be sent, will
> >     the OS now use the mDNS responder to handle the process or will it use
> >     its 'out-of-the-box' DNS responder ???)
>
> Even though mDNSResponder could be used to replace all DNS query
>   handling, it probably won't. The name space provider for Windows which
>   is included in the mDNSResonder project only works for names that end
>   with ".local".
>
> Best Regards,
>
> -Marc

Answer (score 6):

From [Apple's open source implementation of mDNSResponder](https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-541/mDNSCore/DNSCommon.c):

```
// Note: Microsoft's proposed "Link Local Multicast Name Resolution Protocol" (LLMNR) is essentially a limited version of
// Multicast DNS, using the same packet formats, naming syntax, and record types as Multicast DNS, but on a different UDP
// port and multicast address, which means it won't interoperate with the existing installed base of Multicast DNS responders.
// LLMNR uses IPv4 multicast address 224.0.0.252, IPv6 multicast address FF02::0001:0003, and UDP port 5355.
```